# i want to dock User Control

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-controls

I have make user control and inside that user control takes two buttons name dock and close respectively.

Now i want to dock my user control to left when i clicks button dock and close my user control when i clicks  button close..

(i am trying to use by making object of user control but doesnt helps.....)

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Container1 obj = new Container1();
    if (obj.Dock != DockStyle.None) {
        obj.Dock = DockStyle.None;
        MessageBox.Show("Dockstyle is None");
    }
    else {
        obj.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
        MessageBox.Show("Dockstyle is Left");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`obj` needs to be a reference to the instance of your already existing userControl (in your case, the `this` keyword). You have created a new instead of the `Container1` here.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (this.Dock != DockStyle.None)
        {
            this.Dock = DockStyle.None;
            MessageBox.Show("Dockstyle is None");
        }
        else
        {
            this.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
            MessageBox.Show("Dockstyle is Left");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to create the container and then set the `DockStyle` on that container. Instead, you need to set the `DockStyle` of the `UserControl` itself.

Comment: i have to dock my usercontrol not button;;;

Comment: In that case, you need to set the `DockStyle` of the `UserControl` itself, not some dynamically created container. I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: my usercontrol name is container1;;;

Comment: Regardless of what the name is, the control needs to be a parented (whether you do this dynamically or statically). Only then will the `DockStyle` have any effect.